# Flutter testing error: NotInitializedError which involves environment variables (.env)

Tags: flutter, testing, environment-variables, flutter-test

To start, I did review this but to no avail.
[How to access Flutter environment variables from tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686746/how-to-access-flutter-environment-variables-from-tests)

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:main.dart' as app;

import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebaseauth;

import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

import 'basic_app_test.mocks.dart';


@GenerateMocks([firebaseauth.FirebaseAuth])
void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await DotEnv().load(fileName: ".env");

  group('Login Page Tests', () {
    testWidgets('Empty Login Box', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      app.main();

      await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));

      expect(find.byKey(Key('loginButton')), findsOneWidget);

      final Finder loginButton = find.byKey(Key('loginButton'));

      await tester.tap(loginButton);

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(
          find.text(
              'Something went wrong. Please check your email and password and try again.'),
          findsOneWidget);
    });

    testWidgets('Email Login - Proper Credentials',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {

      app.main();

      // Wait for app to reach the login page
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 3));

      final Finder emailBox = find.byKey(Key('emailBox'));
      final Finder passwordBox = find.byKey(Key('passwordBox'));
      final Finder loginButton = find.byKey(Key('loginButton'));
      final Finder welcomeHeader = find.byKey(Key('welcomeHeader'));

      var testPassword = DotEnv().env['TEST_PASSWORD'];
      await tester.enterText(passwordBox, testPassword);

      expect(find.byKey(Key('loginButton')), findsOneWidget);
      await tester.tap(loginButton);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 5));

      // SHOULD BE EXPECTING A WIDGET IN THE NEXT WINDOW
      expect(welcomeHeader, findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

I have a group of tests.  The first one runs just fine.  The second one runs into an error when the testPassword variable is created.

Here is the error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NotInitializedError was thrown running a test:
Instance of 'NotInitializedError'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      DotEnv.env (package:flutter_dotenv/src/dotenv.dart:42:7)
#1      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/WEBDEV/EndevStudios/MedicalApp/gshDevWork/medical-app-frontend/integration_test/basic_app_test.dart:52:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

The test description was:
  Email Login - Proper Credentials
```

The `.env` file is located at the root.

My `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2

flutter:
    #Integration Testing
    - .env
```

**What I've tried:**
Most solutions involve some variation of `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` or  `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` as well as `await DotEnv().load(fileName: ".env");` and `await DotEnv().load();`.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change from

```
await DotEnv().load(fileName: ".env");
```

to:

```
await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
```

using the latest library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in youre tests this:

```
// Loading from a static string.
dotenv.testLoad(fileInput: '''FOO=foo
BAR=bar
''');
```

or

```
// Loading from a file synchronously.
dotenv.testLoad(fileInput: File('test/.env').readAsStringSync());
```